She knocked my glasses flying and they fell on the floor

She knocked my glasses flying and they fell on the floor.

What is the function of the word 'flying' here? Does it describe the subject 'she' or the object 'my glasses'? Is it functioning as a gerund or a present participle?

She knocked the glasses, causing them to 'fly' through the air.

The price sent my head spinning.  The participle  declares the state into which the object is put by the action of the verb.  It is not a gerund but more like a participial adjective inasmuch as it has to do with the state of the object.

You'll find the phrase "knocked [someone/something] flying" in most dictionaries.
To knock something just means to strike or hit something. On its own, it can mean anything from a light tap to a heavy impact, so it is often worked into a phrase to describe either the intensity or the outcome of the knock.
For example:

Knocked for six or knocked flying mean a heavy hit that caused a person to be visibly thrown
Knocked over or knocked down tend to mean it caused something or someone to fall to the floor
Knocked out or knocked senseless mean it caused a person to go unconscious
Knocked loose suggests a light tap that caused something to loosen rather than break

And there are many more, most of which you will also find in a dictionary.
